# eqref fails in local compilation, but works on Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, babel, right-to-left

I am trying to transition from Overleaf to a local workspace and set up VSCode with the Latex Workshop extension as my Latex IDE, and I faced a weird problem. I work on Hebrew documents and I use babel and lualatex. Here's the example I was playing with:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

% Font setup
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Miriam CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{tt}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Miriam Mono CLM}

\babelfont{david}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{David CLM}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\OverSet}{ O{0cm} m m }{
    \overset{\raise #1 \hbox{\(#2\)}}{#3}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pythagoras}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
לפי משוואה
\eqref{eq:pythagoras}
נסיק כי
\begin{align*}
c^4 \OverSet[0.05cm]{\scriptstyle\eqref{eq:pythagoras}}{=} (a^2 + b^2)^2
\end{align*}
נמשיך
\end{document}
```

Both on Overleaf and locally I get that the reference to the equation above the equal sign is not directly above it:

[image]

The weird part is that this seems to happen only in the `align` and `gather` environments. Using an `equation` environment (or simply `\[ \]`) doesn't cause this problem. I found that wrapping the `align` environment in the `\babelsublr{}` command fixes this issue:

```latex
\babelsublr{
\begin{align*}
c^4 \OverSet[0.05cm]{\scriptstyle\eqref{eq:pythagoras}}{=} (a^2 + b^2)^2
\end{align*}}
```

[image]

So it looks like the problem is solved and this is the solution I have been using until now. When I tried the same example on my local machine in VSCode, it didn't compile and it claimed it couldn't find the `eq:pythagoras` reference. Removing the `babelsublr{}` command made it compile, but the problem of the reference not being centered has returned. Another weird result I found is that if I comment out the remainder of the code (The line "נמשיך" in the above example) and end the document with this `align` environment wrapped inside `\babelsublr{}`, it compiles successfully, and the result is correct.

I am very confused by this. I thought that using `\babelsublr{}` solves this issue and it always worked for me on Overleaf, but when I try it locally, it doesn't work unless it's the end of the document. On my machine I use TexLive 2023, and I compile using the default "latexmk (lualatex)" recipe of the Latex Workshop extension.

Can anyone explain why this works fine on Overleaf but not locally and how to fix it? Maybe there is a better solution than `\babelsublr{}` that would work both locally and on Overleaf?

Comment: May be the problem is what do you compile with. The `bidi method is available only in `luatex`.

Comment: I am using LuaTex