Hebrew in title is reversed
Trying to reach Hello World level here but having difficulties setting up a title page. After searching online for a while I figured it's best to use polyglossia for my Hebrew documents. I was trying to set a title page:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Latin Modern Roman}

 
\begin{document}

\title{שם ומספר הקורס}
\author{השם שלי}
\maketitle

\end{document}

which resulted in:

The author name is in reverse (should display "השם שלי") and clearly the year 2024 is also reversed. I suspect it has something to do with how /maketitle works (probably not compatible with right-to-left written languages). Would appericate any help.

You could try with babel (https://i.sstatic.net/Ddle2xK4.png), see e.g. here for an example with hebrew https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/713464/36296

Does it work outside the title? That is, you just add some text to the document to check if your suspicion is correct?

Use xelatex. If you do that, you get bidi support.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354676/ for a couple of different ways to set up a document with Hebrew, English and, in this case, Greek. One uses polyglossia and one babel. Disclaimer: one of the answers is mine. Note that the answer which isn't mine is more careful and more comprehensive, even though mine is the accepted one. It also works with luatex as well as xetex. (I don't know why the OP accepted mine. Apparently precisely because it was less comprehensive.)

Thanks everyone, but I've actually resorted to using LyX for my math documents, so sadly I won't be learning LaTeX :)
